# Listen to Custom DOM Events in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I use an Angular library, which has a component, which uses CustomEvents to dispatch something, like this:

```
const domEvent = new CustomEvent('unselect', {
   bubbles: true
});
 this.elementRef.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(domEvent);
```

How can I listen to this Event in the parent component?

I know it is discouraged and I should normally use `EventEmitters`. But I have no access to overwrite the child component and there is no `@Output` Event defined. So this is the only thing I could use.

Comment: did the answer and working example help you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [HostListener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) to listen for this custom event. The following example triggers the custom event from a child component with the parent component listening for the event. You can even use args (second argument) such as `['$event.target']` to determine what element triggered the event.

This uses `ngAfterViewInit()` lifecycle hook, but it's just for demonstration and just to ensure the element ref is ready.

Parent:

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  @HostListener('unselect', ['$event.target'])
  onUnSelect(el) {
    console.log(el); // element that triggered event, in this case HTMLUnknownElement
    console.log('unselect triggered');
  }
}
```

Child:

```
import { Component, Input, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const domEvent = new CustomEvent('unselect', { bubbles: true });    
    this.el.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(domEvent);
  }
}
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yytzqx) in action.

Hopefully that helps!