# Event emitter from StencilJS to Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, stenciljs

I need to listen the event that a child component fired. In my case, I have a "tabs" component made in stencil v1 that has this structure...

**abc-tabs.tsx**

```
import { Component, h, Listen, Element, State, Event, Method, EventEmitter } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'abc-tabs'
})
export class AepTabs {
  @Element() tabs: HTMLElement;
  @State() initIndex: number = 0;
  @Event() tabClick: EventEmitter; // <---------- HERE
  private tabsElements;
  private tabsElementList: Array<any> = [];
  private tabTitleElements: any;

  componentWillLoad() {
    this.createTabsTitles(this.tabs.querySelectorAll('abc-tab'));
  }

  componentDidLoad() {
    this.addTitleEvents();
  }

  addTitleEvents() {
    this.tabTitleElements = this.tabs.getElementsByClassName('tab-title');
    [].forEach.call(this.tabTitleElements, (tab, pos) => {
      tab.addEventListener('click', () => {
        this.tabClick.emit(tab);
        this.activeTabs(pos);
      });
    });
    this.activeTabs(this.initIndex);
  }

  createTabsTitles(tabsList: NodeList) {
    this.tabsElements = tabsList;
    [].forEach.call(this.tabsElements, tab => {
      this.tabsElementList.push(
        <div class="tab-title" data-automation={tab.titletab.toString().toLowerCase()}>
          <span>{tab.titletab}</span>
        </div>
      );
    });
  }

  @Method()
  activeTabs(index: number) {
    this.tabTitleElements = this.tabs.getElementsByClassName('tab-title');
    [].forEach.call(this.tabTitleElements, (tab, pos) => {
      if (index === pos) {
        tab.classList.add('active');
        tab.classList.remove('inactive');
      } else {
        tab.classList.remove('active');
        tab.classList.add('inactive');
      }
    });

    [].forEach.call(this.tabsElements, (tab, pos) => {
      if (index === pos) {
        tab.classList.add('active');
        tab.classList.remove('inactive');
      } else {
        tab.classList.remove('active');
        tab.classList.add('inactive');
      }
    });
  }

  // HERE --------------------------------------------------------
  @Listen('tabClick') 
  clicktabHandler(event: CustomEvent) {
    this.activeTabs(event.detail);
  }
  // HERE --------------------------------------------------------

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <nav>{this.tabsElementList}</nav>
        <div>
          <div>
            <slot />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So, in my angular project I using the stencil component.

**detail.component.html**

```
<abc-tabs>
  <abc-tab titletab="My first tab">
    <!-- content here -->
  </abc-tab>
  <abc-tab titletab="My second tab" >
    <!-- content here -->
  </abc-tab>
</abc-tabs>
```

And everything works perfect, but now I need to @Listen (in Angular) the event that is fired up when some of the tabs was clicked, so I was doing this in my detail.component.ts class:

**detail.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Listen, Watch } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-detail',
  templateUrl: './detail.component.html'
})
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  @Listen('tabClick') // <--- ERROR HERE
  clicktabHandler(event: CustomEvent) {
    console.log('has clicked!!!! ', event.detail);
  }
}
```

but, it throws an error in ***detail.component.ts***:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
```

It seems that 'clicktab' it's something that Angular can not see even if I import @Listen from @stencil/core.

Any hint?

Comment: I doubt you can use Stencil's `@Listen` decorator on an Angular component... the `@Listen` counterpart of Angular is `@Input`.

Comment: Also your event name is `tabClick` and not `clicktab`.

Comment: @MichalCumpl right! but same result :(

Comment: @SimonHänisch But it's a stencil's component, and is not "Input" a property to send variables to child component between angular components not a third party lib...? like stencil?

Comment: Can you please update your code then? You should be using either @HostListener('tabClick') in your ts file or (tabClick)="handleTabClick()" in your Angular template.

Comment: This is imho a duplicate to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53397035/listen-to-custom-dom-events-in-angular

Comment: @MichalCumpl HostListener was the solution! (also code updated)

Comment: @RicardoGonzales in the code above you're importing the `Component` decorator from `@angular/core`, not @stencil/core`, so how could this be a stencil component?

Comment: Thanks. This question was more useful than 'Stenciljs Angular integration' docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `@HostListener('tabClick')` instead of `@Listen('tabClick')`.

Answer (score 1):

@Listen is the Stencil directive and @HostListener is an Angular directive. Please use the correct directive in the appropriate project.