# How to to listen to an html element that is outside angular app?

Tags: angular, angular-renderer2

I have two HTML elements below,

```
<p #test>with reference</p>
<p id="with-id">need to access without template reference</p>
```

I know I can access the first P element with the template reference with renderer2 but I am not sure how I access the second P tag without template reference.

In our case,

Our modal is served outside our angular app. I need to add a click event to the close button of the modal which I directly don't have access to.

Below is my code,

```
this.unlistenCloseButton = this.renderer2.listen('outside-html-element', 'close', event => {
    console.log(`on close`);
});
```

Is there a way to add a reference to that close button and pass it to the angular's renderer2?

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/renderer2-example-2-nzc3rn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) code demonstrating with two P tag.

Comment: the amount of code provided is not enough for a clear answer, please provide a stackblitz with the issue or some extra details!

Comment: this modal is driven outside our angular app. I cannot add it on stackblitz. but my question is very straightforward

Comment: use custom events, dispatch them outside angular, and listen to them using hostlistener. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53397035/listen-to-custom-dom-events-in-angular)

Comment: @NarenMurali, I updated my question with stackblitz

Answer (score 1):

On the popup close, am not sure if you use jquery or just javascript, but you need to call this below code (when the modal closes). Which will create a custom event.

```
const event = new Event('popupClosed');

// Dispatch the event.
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Then in the angular component listen for this document event using hostlistener.

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  @HostListener('popupClosed', ['$event.target'])
  onUnSelect(el) {
    console.log(el); // element that triggered event, in this case HTMLUnknownElement
    console.log('popupClosed');
  }
}
```

Code taken for the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53397035/listen-to-custom-dom-events-in-angular)

Comment: I don't have access to the library. I cannot write a custom event on that library.

Comment: @anonymous The library will have a callback when the popup is closed, add the custom event emit there!

Comment: This library is hosted on a different server which I don't have access to

Comment: Upvoted your answer. I somehow managed to add the custom event to the library. Now the component I want to listen to is a sibling of the modal rendered. How can I listen to the custom event?

Answer (score 1):

**Disclamer** I don't know if this work, but Angular is not more than javascript. You can use `document.getElementById` and you can use fromEvent rxjs

```
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document:Document) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const el=this.document.getElementById('with-id')
    fromEvent(el,'click').subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res)
    })
  }
```

NOTE: I choose use rxjs fromEvent operator, because allow get an observable, subscribe/unsubscribe, etc.etc. But you can also use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) at javascript style

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/renderer2-example-2-k7qu9h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Update** unsubscribe is important. So we can use some like

```
subscription:Subscription;
addEvent()
{
   if (this.subscription)
   {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
      this.subscription=null
   }
   const el=this.document.getElementById('with-id')
   this.subscription=fromEvent(el,'click')
             .pipe(take(1))
             .subscribe(res=>{
                console.log(res)
             })
}
```

Comment: actually, the close button element appears on the document only when you open the modal. I tried your code, on after view init, the element is null

Comment: If you open the modal in a function, try some like `open(){...here you open the modal..;setTimeout(()=>{const el=...;fromEvent(el,..)})`

Comment: I am afraid this will create too many event listener everytime you open the modal

Comment: you can store in a variable the subscription or use pipe(take(1)), see updated answer

Comment: Answer upvoted. First of all, the button to open the modal dynamically appears on all products. Secondly, when the open modal method is called, it makes an HTTP call to render the modal